# Invalid Escape Sequence in Java when assign a string value

Tags: java

I am getting

> Invalid Escape Sequence Error

in Java When I am trying to assign this value

```
String username = "americas\$yoma002";
```

Comment: you need to use 2 \\ to escape the \ in java

Comment: If that doesn't work, try this `String username = "americas\\\$yoma002";`

Answer (score 1):

Replace backslash with double backslash

like this :

`String username = "americas\\$yoma002";`

Answer (score 1):

Use double slash `\\` instead of the single slash to escaping the backslashes, 
like:

```
String username = "americas\\$yoma002";
```

Refer the [Escape Sequences for Character and String Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6)